# How to list all available Kafka brokers in a cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am writing a shell script to monitor kafka brokers.

I have gone through some links and found that if ZooKeeper contains a list of brokers, and if, in this list, the IP address is present, then a kafka broker is running.

I want a command that I can use in my shell script to get the broker list and check whether kafka is running.

Is there any `curl` command to get the kafka cluster status like elasticsearch?

Comment: I know that inside the zookeper-shell script in Kafka's bin folder you can call `ls /brokers/ids` to get the ids of the brokers currently alive. I don't know how to pass that as a parameter to the script though...

Answer (score 169, accepted):

This command will give you the list of the active brokers between brackets:

```
./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response.
I am getting the following error when I run the command `Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xxx:2181 Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[0, 1, 3]`

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa, that means you're alive brokers are the ones with id 0, 1 and 3.

Comment: Sir is it possible to get the ips of the brokers , else how can I will be able to check which broker is alive and which is not.
Thank you

Comment: i'm not sure about that, but when you start the brokers, you use a config file, in which you assing the ids... maybe you can build a lookup table at that point to get the ip from the broker id?

Comment: I have added an answer further down this question to help you out @ShivkumarMallesappa

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1:9092

Comment: This answer would be perfect if it had at the end: get /brokers/id/0 for example. There you get the configured host.

Comment: Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[1001, 1002, 1003]
[2023-01-31 18:24:09,736] ERROR Exiting JVM with code 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils)

I got an error. :|

Answer (score 85):

**Alternate way using Zk-Client:**

If you do not prefer to pass arguments to `./zookeeper-shell.sh` and want to see the broker details from Zookeeper CLI, you need to install standalone Zookeeper (As traditional Kafka do not comes up with Jline JAR).

Once you install(unzip) the standalone Zookeeper,then:

- Run the Zookeeper CLI: 
  `$ zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181` `#Make sure your Broker is already running`
- If it is successful, you can see the Zk client running as:

`WATCHER::`

```
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0]
```

- From here you can explore the broker details using various commands:

`$  ls /brokers/ids`   `# Gives the list of active brokers`
`$  ls /brokers/topics` `#Gives the list of topics`
`$  get /brokers/ids/0` `#Gives more detailed information of the broker id '0'`

Comment: how to fire these commands (ls /brokers/ids) using a bash script ?

Comment: When you run Zookeeper CLI, you will get a prompt. You have run these commands on that prompt.

Comment: It says `Node doesn't exist`.

Comment: This was the answer which helped me! When I concatenated the connection script with the query script (zookeeper-shell.bat localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids) I got the following error: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/ids. But if I runned the connector script individually (zookeeper-shell.bat localhost:2181) and after I runned the query (ls /brokers/ids) I got proper result!

Comment: One single command "zkCli -server localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids".

Answer (score 31):

```
echo dump | nc localhost 2181 | grep brokers
```

(replace localhost with the host where zookeeper is running)

Comment: This not always list me the brokers, sometimes list is empty. I don't know why exactly, it seems to happen because nc output is not synchronous

Comment: This way is convenient because you can easily pipe the output in `wc -l` command

Comment: To @dhalfageme: The reason it's not consistent for you is because `nc` has quit just a nanosecond before the reply data came back. The way to make it consistent is to ask `nc` to wait for at least 1 second before quiting: `nc -q 1 localhost 2181`

Answer (score 14):

If you are using new version of Kafka e.g. 2.3.3 (or Confluent 5.3.3 and higher), you can use

```
kafka-broker-api-versions  --bootstrap-server BROKER | grep 9092
```

You just need to pass one of the brokers.

For Confluent and Kafka interoperability see

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html

Comment: If available, it's the cleanest option IMO

Comment: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: 'grep' is a Linux command line. Just drop it and run kafka-broker-api-versions  --bootstrap-server BROKER

Answer (score 10):

Here are a couple of quick functions I use when bash scripting Kafka Data Load into Demo Environments. In this example I use HDP with no security, but it is easily modified to other environments and intended to be quick and  functional rather than particularly robust.

The first retrieves the address of the first ZooKeeper node from the config:

```
ZKS1=$(cat /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client/conf/zoo.cfg | grep server.1)
[[ ${ZKS1} =~ server.1=(.*?):[0-9]*:[0-9]* ]]
export ZKADDR=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}:2181
echo "using ZooKeeper Server $ZKADDR"
```

The second retrieves the Broker IDs from ZooKeeper:

```
echo "Fetching list of Kafka Brokers"
export BROKERIDS=$(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh ${ZKADDR} <<< 'ls /brokers/ids' | tail -1)
export BROKERIDS=${BROKERIDS//[!0-9 ]/}
echo "Found Kafka Broker IDS: $BROKERIDS"
```

The third parses ZooKeeper again to retrieve the list of Kafka Brokers Host:port ready for use in the command-line client:

```
unset BROKERS
for i in $BROKERIDS
do
DETAIL=$(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh ${ZKADDR} <<< "get /brokers/ids/$i")
[[ $DETAIL =~ PLAINTEXT:\/\/(.*?)\"\] ]]
if [ -z ${BROKERS+x} ]; then BROKERS=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; else 
BROKERS="${BROKERS},${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi
done
echo "Found Brokerlist: $BROKERS"
```

Answer (score 4):

On MacOS, can try:

```
brew tap let-us-go/zkcli
```

```
brew install zkcli
```

or

```
brew install let-us-go/zkcli/zkcli
brew link --overwrite zkcli
```

```
zkcli ls /brokers/ids
zkcli get /brokers/ids/1
```

Answer (score 2):

To use zookeeper commands with shell script try

zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids" | tail -n 1. The last line usually has the response details

Answer (score 2):

#### Using [Confluent's REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#cluster-v3) API v3:

```bash
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" localhost:8082/v3/clusters
```

where `localhost:8082` is Kafka Proxy address.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```
#!/bin/bash

ZK_HOST="localhost"
ZK_PORT=2181


for i in `echo dump | nc $ZK_HOST $ZK_PORT | grep brokers`
do
    echo $i
    DETAIL=`zkCli -server "$ZK_HOST:$ZK_PORT" get $i 2>/dev/null | tail -n 1`
    echo $DETAIL
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This window command will give you the list of the active brokers between brackets:

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-shell.bat localhost:2181  ls /brokers/ids
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In KRaft based deployment, you can use the below command to check the status of a broker:

```
$ kafka-metadata-quorum --bootstrap-server <broker_name>:9092 describe --status
```

Repeat the with correct `broker_name` for all the nodes in the cluster.